# What git merge strategy was used when making a merge?

Tags: git, merge

I just found out about the `recursive` merge strategy can have an `ours` parameter. There is also the `ours` strategy.

So, if more people work on a file and push it to a remote repository, but I come and do a `git pull -s ours` then I will completely disregard the remote changes and put mine instead.

I find this quite confusing because, the file doesn't seem to have any history left from the other people. To see that, one must write `git log --follow <file>`. And also, looking at the merge commit, there is no evidence that the file was affected.

How can one know when something like this happened? Is it possible to see the merge strategy used? Or, is it possible to see that the file history was altered?

Answer (score 2):

The file history was not altered and there were no additional changes in the merge commit to be shown. Using `-X ours` or `-s ours` just says which side of the merged trees to use (at conflict or always) so there is no manipulated history. And whether `-X ours` is there or not is of course not detectable. Because you can also simply do not use `-X ours` and resolve any arising conflict with taking your side of the merge completely. Would be the same result. It is the job of the merger to do the right thing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is more with the `git pull -s ours`. If I do that and look at the file history with `git log <file>` I don't see the other people changes. It's like they disappeared. And I can't even see when that happened because the merge doesn't appear in the history.

Comment: Well, `-s ours` also just says "take all my versions from the merge" just for all files, not only for conflicted files. The merge is of course part of the history and you have the others peoples changes. When there is the merge, the history goes two paths. If you only follow the first parent, you will of course only see your changes, if you follow the second parent, you will see the changes of the other people. The merge did not introduce new changes, thus you do not see a diff in the merge. You just selected one version of a file or the other in the merge which is the sense of a merge ...

Comment: ... to decide which version of the file is the correct result for the merge or how to combine the changes in the two development branches. Also `-s ours` is just a shortcut that can easily be achieved without using that option actually. But you can check whether it was used (or commands done to produce the same result) by diffing the post-merge state against the parents of the merge. If there is no diff to one of the parents, this parent was taken completely, discarding the changes on the other, just as the documentaition of `-s ours` explains.

Comment: Thanks Björn, it makes sense what you are saying. So, basically a "merge" can actually say just take my changes and throw all the other ones away. You "merged" your branch but actually you just forcefully put only your changes. And yet, there is no easy way to see when someone is doing that.

Comment: Depends on how you define "easy"

Comment: Easy would be to look at the history and see or be warned when the user preferred to "merge" using only  his version of the file. I would like to know in my repos when that happened. If I have to dig down through all the merges and do git diff on the parents and such, that I think is hard.

Comment: Well, there is no reason for a warning as it is a normal situation. You could maybe add some hook that checks this and either informs you or denies the push or creates a tag on that merge or similar.

Answer (score 1):

(This is meant to add to [Björn Kautler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693666/1256452), but is too long and format-y for a comment.)

**Edit**: to find a `-s ours` merge, compare the merge to its first and second parents (and additional parents if any).  If it is identical to the first, but different from some other, it is a merge that was either done with `-s ours`, or done with manual resolving that produced the equivalent.

As a shell one-liner (well... a very long one line, and untested):

```
git rev-list --merges --parents HEAD |
  while read commit first rest; do
    test $(git diff --name-only $commit $first | wc -l) -ne 0 && continue;
    set -- $rest;
    anydiff=false;
    for i do
      test $(git diff --name-only $commit $i | wc -l) -ne 0 && anydiff=true;
    done;
    $anydiff && echo "merge $commit is (effectively) -s ours";
  done
```

That is, find all merges reachable from here (HEAD).  While there are some:

- If `$commit` differs from `$first` (its first parent), skip: not `-s ours`.
- For the remaining parents: if `$commit` differs from `$i`, make a note that it is different (could `break` here too for a minor speedup).
- If same as first parent but different from some other parent, gripe.

---

There is a big and important difference between `-X ours` and `-s ours`.  It *is* [called out in the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies):

> [-s] ours
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the `-Xours` option to the *recursive* merge strategy.

I think this note is not really strong enough.  Although I am still working on it, here is what I say about this in my "merge" chapter:

---

We have already seen the `-X theirs` option;
`-X ours` corresponds to Mercurial's `:merge-local` tool
and simply chooses our change
when there is a conflict.
For Carol's merge,
this would mean she would keep Alice's changes
in favor of Bob's,
although she would still pick up Bob's changes
where there is no conflict.

*[...]*

Besides these `-X` options,
`git merge` provides the `-s strategy` option.<sup>12</sup>
Most of these are specialized enough for us to ignore here,
but we need to call one out in particular
because it is easy to misuse.

Confusingly,
`git merge` provides `-s ours`,
but `-s ours` has a *very different action*
than `-X ours`.
Git's `-s ours`
corresponds to Mercurial's `:local` merge tool,
whose action is to *ignore and discard every target file*
(or *other* file in Mercurial),
keeping the source tree the same as in the current commit.
The principle use for this kind of merge in Git
is to *kill off* a topic or feature branch,
i.e., to bring it back into the main-line branch.
This keeps it recorded in the commit DAG for historical examination,
while discarding from the main-line branch
all the work that was done in it,
marking it as a failed experiment.
(We can, of course, do the same in Mercurial,
using `:local`.
However, Mercurial's branches cannot be killed,
so there is no real point to this.)

---

<sup>12</sup>This can be spelled `--strategy strategy`,
but I find this is actually more confusing
than just remembering `-s` and `-X`,
with `-X` standing for “extended”.

Comment: Thanks! I think the script will come in useful. Currently it might produce some false positives.